# Rails - Difference between accessing model information via send() vs index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model M that has a column C. At a certain point in my project I have a specific instance of M stored in memory, m. I also have the string "c", and I have found that both of these lines do the same thing (as far as I can tell):

```
m.send("c")
m["c"]
```

Is there a difference? Is there any reason to use one over the other?

P.S. - If you can come up with a better title, please comment, I had a hard time making an appropriate title.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be using:

```
m.c
```

`m["c"]` is a shortcut for `m.attributes['c']`.

`m.send("c")` is used when you need to construct the method name to call dynamically:

```
index_type = "chapter"
m.send("open_to_#{index_type}", 1) # calls m.open_to_chapter(1)
```

Comment: I don't think I can use m.c in my case though. I get the c from a string. Is there a way to call m.c if all I have is m and "c"?

Comment: Then I would stick with `m["c"]` or `m.attributes["c"]` if you are accessing model attributes.